Plotting circles at each point in space
I am trying to make a plot on x-y grid such that, at each coordinate such that x=y, i need to get a plot. For this purpose, i have created a function which can generate a parametric plot of a circle. But now i am struggling how to place these circles at desired x-y coordinate. Here i have normalized the amplitude so that the radius of the circle is always same for any given pair of x,y. The function is as follows:
circp[x_, y_, t_] := Module[{eox, eoy, con, ex, ey, out, phase},
  eox = 2*x;
  eoy = 2*y;
  con = Sqrt[eox^2 + eoy^2];
  phase = Pi;
  ex = (eox*Cos[t])/con;
  ey = (-eoy*Sin[t + phase])/con;
  out = {ex, ey}]

plot = ParametricPlot[circp[1, 1, t], {t, 0, 2*Pi}]


Try: Graphics[Table[Circle[{2 x, 2 x}, 1], {x, -5, 5}], Axes -> True]

If I understand you right, why not use Graphics to draw the circle? something like
circles = Table[Circle[circp[1, 1, t]], {t, 0, 2*Pi, Pi/10}];
Graphics[circles, Axes -> True]


circles = Table[Circle[circp[1, 1, t]], {t, 0, 2*Pi, Pi/2}];
Graphics[circles, Axes -> True]



Thanks for the help, I will update the question and ask it as a new one.
